# Filtering collections using row constructors

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-collection

How does one filter a [Doctrine collection](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) using a [row constructor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34270/95143) similar to what can be done with SQL such as `SELECT whatever FROM t WHERE (col1, col2) IN ((val1a, val2a), (val1b, val2b), ...);`?

Comment: Probably using the QueryBuilders option to [build Expressions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/query-builder.html#building-expressions), possibly with [this extension](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) also installed. Dunno, haven't tried. What you found thus far that you can add to the question?

Comment: @rkeet  I used a workaround using `andX` and `orX` and found using `...` came in very handy.  Regardless of whether I will use [this extension](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) for this need, I never knew about that extension, and I will definitely investigate for other needs.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Would be nice if you could provide a row constructor example as an answer when you figure that out though. Would like a tag when you do, can think of a few possible use cases in current projects for that, so would like to see an approach of how to.